# how to find array element from user input

Tags: c

friend i am new in c ,so i face problem in a ,code, plz if there is any wrong in my logic,take it as a pardon eye,

I am trying to find the element in a two dimensional array, so i have declare a two dimensional array in my code, i will take a user input, the input will compare with data in an full array a  column index of two dimensional array, if any data found similar of that column index then it will give the same row data of another column of array. if  i give a input in my code it  is giving output of the number is not in array index, though the number is in the array index, so i dont understand where is my fault.
plz help me to fix the problem. 
here is my code :

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  int main()
  {
   int arr[10][3]={{1,5},

             {2,8},

             {3,27},

            { 4,64},

             {5,125},

             {6,216},

            { 7,343},

             {8,512},

            { 9,729},

            { 10,1000}};

             int i, num;

         printf("Enter a number\n");
         scanf("%d",&num);
         for(i=0;i<10;i++)
         {
            if (num==arr[i][0])
            printf("%d",arr[i][1]);
            break;

         }    

            if (num==10)

            printf("the number is not there");

            return 0;   
             }
```

Comment: You have an atrocious indentation style, I suggest you try and change that. It will prevent you from making errors like these.

Comment: Also, SMS-style text is not very readable and makes the post look amateurish. (Use "please" instead of "plz" and use proper capitalization.)

Answer (score 3):

You have an errant semi-colon:

```
if (num==10);          
    printf("the number is not there");
```

That call to `printf` will run each time because there is no body for the `if` statement. With better formatting:

```
if (num==10);          

printf("the number is not there");
```

---

As @zoska points out, you also have the same bug here:

```
if (num==arr[i][0]);
```

Comment: in two places (also `if (num==arr[i][0]);`!

Comment: @zoska: Thanks, missed that one.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following **three** changes at the minimum:

Change `int arr[10][3]` to `int arr[10][2]`

Change

```
if (num==arr[i][0]);
            printf("%d",arr[i][1]);
```

to

```
if (num == arr[i][0]) {              
    printf("%d",arr[i][1]);
}
```

Change

```
if (num==10);          
        printf("the number is not there");
```

to

```
if (i == 10) {          // note: 'num' changed to 'i'
    printf("the number is not there");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this in the future

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arr[10][2] = {
        {1,5},
        {2,8},
        {3,27},
        {4,64},
        {5,125},
        {6,216},
        {7,343},
        {8,512},
        {9,729},
        {10,1000}
    };

    int i, num;

    printf("Enter a number\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (num==arr[i][0]) {
            printf("%d", arr[i][1]);
            break;
        }
    }    

    if (i == 10) {
        printf("the number is not there");
    }

    return 0;   
}
```